# Log File not created using log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j2

I changing my log4j lib from log4j to log4j2.

However, for the new log4j2, there is not log file created.

```
package log4j;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class Log4jExample {
    
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jExample.class);
    
       public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException{  
          log.info("log4j2");  
       }  
}
```

My properties file as below

```
status = info
property.basePath = D:/

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileLogger
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}../app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern= ${basePath}/app_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %level [%t] [%l] - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
```

And my project directory setting as per below

[image]

Can you guide me, what is wrong with the configuration or project directory setting?

Comment: Hi,Managed to get the log file out. But it is an empty file.

-Dlog4j.configurationFile=C:\Users\xxx\eclipse-workspace\log4j\src\resources\log4j2.properties

But I got the error main WARN No Root logger was configured, creating default ERROR-level Root logger with Console appender

Comment: logger.app.name = XXX (package name)
logger.app.level = info, error
logger.app.additivity = false
logger.app.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingFile

Adding the configuration and it works.

Comment: Please update your post instead of providing generally useful information in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
logger.app.name = package_name
logger.app.level = info, error
logger.app.additivity = false
logger.app.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LogToRollingFile
```

Comment: Please add to your answer: How does this solve the problem?

Comment: Hi,
The mistake here is I did'nt mention the correct package name. You need to refer to you program package and define it at log4j.properties file.

Comment: Please update your post instead of providing generally useful information in a comment.